# Duplicate rows for dates between interval

Tags: python, pandas

I have a frame like this:

| ID | Start | Stop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-05 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-10 |

And I want to duplicate the rows so I end up with a table like this:

| ID | Start | Stop | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-05 | 2020-01-01 |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-05 | 2020-01-02 |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-05 | 2020-01-03 |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-05 | 2020-01-04 |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-05 | 2020-01-05 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-10 | 2020-01-01 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-10 | 2020-01-02 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-10 | 2020-01-03 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-10 | 2020-01-04 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-10 | 2020-01-05 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-10 | 2020-01-06 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-10 | 2020-01-07 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-10 | 2020-01-08 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-10 | 2020-01-09 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-10 | 2020-01-10 |

I am however lost on how to achieve this, any pointers?

Answer (score 3):

Generate a list using `date_range()` then expand it using `explode()`

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""ID  Start   Stop
1   2020-01-01  2020-01-05
2   2020-01-01  2020-01-10
"""), sep="\t", index_col=0)
df.Start = pd.to_datetime(df.Start)
df.Stop = pd.to_datetime(df.Stop)


df.assign(Date=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: pd.date_range(r["Start"], r["Stop"]), axis=1)).explode("Date")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into pandas DataFrames' methods `iterrows` to iterate over the rows of your original DataFrame and the function `date_range` to create the dates between each Start and Stop date.

Create a new DataFrame for each row from your original DataFrame (`df`) and then combine all the created DataFrames into one big DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd

expanded_dfs = []
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    dates = pd.date_range(row["Start"], row["Stop"], freq="D")
    expanded = pd.DataFrame({
        "Start": row["Start"],
        "End": row["Stop"],
        "Date": dates,
        "ID": row["ID"]
    })
    expanded_dfs.append(expanded)
pd.concat(expanded_dfs)
```